# Azure FunctionApps (Isolated worker) with Serilog unable to resolve

Tags: c#, azure-functions, serilog

I'm using Azure Functionapp (version 4) isolated worker process. I have configured Serilog in the program.cs file as below. But in my actual function when I inject `Serilog.ILogger`, it fails with error during runtime, unable to resolve `Serilog.ILogger`.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
     .ConfigureServices(s =>
     {
         s.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
         s.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();


         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Application")
             .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", "Dev")
             .MinimumLevel.Warning()
              .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
              .CreateLogger();


         //configure seriLog
         s.AddLogging(lb =>
         {
             lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
         });

         s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
         {
             // The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.
             // Log levels can also be configured using appsettings.json. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs
             LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                 == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

             if (toRemove is not null)
             {
                 options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
             }
         });
     })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I Also tried using the below method to register Serilog but its still fails -

```
 s.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) =>
     {
         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
             .CreateLogger();
         return new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true);
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason that `Serilog.ILogger` is not resolvable is that `AddSerilog` doesn't add `Serilog.ILogger` as a resolvable service as you *shouldn't* be requesting a `Serilog.ILogger`.

The `AddSerilog` that you are using is an extension method to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder` and it adds Serilog as an `ILoggerProvider` ([see source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/b524ab61765c7576971563355b5e68d8cd769ed9/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/SerilogLoggingBuilderExtensions.cs#L35)). That way, when you request an `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`, it will build an logger that logs to all the registered `ILoggerProvider`s as Serilog may not be the only provider.

Instead, you should be requesting that an `Microsoft.Extension.Logging.ILogger<T>` be injection into your function.

If you *really* want an `Serilog.ILogger` injected, then you need to use extension `AddSerilog` on the `IServiceCollection` **and provide** `Log.Logger`. The source code for that function is [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/52f29a676444e58015863ab92c1432357d0fa03f/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/SerilogServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L56).

#### A summary:

You should be using any of the following:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .UseSerilog()
    .Build()

// OR

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSerilog();
    })
    .Build();

// OR

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.ConfigureLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog());
    })
    .Build();
```

and then injecting `ILogger<T>` is the recommended practice since your functions shouldn't know anything about Serilog. You also never need to specify Serilog's static `Log.Logger` as it will be used by default if ILogger is not specified.

And here's what you should do if you want to inject a `Serilog.ILogger`.

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
    })
    .Build();
```

I didn't specify whether you need to use dispose or not, that's up to your implementation.